# flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I actually have two questions.

1. I'm trying to add a String type object to an existing array in Firestore like this:

```dart
  addWalletToUser(coinAddress) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser());
    try {
      await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid)
          .updateData({
            "cryptoAddresses": FieldValue.arrayUnion(coinAddress)
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print('error caught: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This results in the following error: `flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

2. My second question is why my code in this if-statement is carried out while `addWalletToUser` should return **null**:

```dart
if (addWalletToUser(_textController.text) != null)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `addWalletToUser` function is `async` so it returns a `Future` which is not null. What you are returning inside the `async` function is obtained as `await addWalletToUser(text)` which will now give null. Also what is the function `FieldValue.arrayUnion` returning?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post, so that it can be answered with a single answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding this error:

> flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List'

This means you are trying to do assign a String to a List (as in list = string).

The `arrayUnion` takes a parameter of type `List<dynamic>`:

```
  static FieldValue arrayUnion(List<dynamic> elements) =>
      FieldValue._(FieldValueType.arrayUnion, elements);
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/field_value.dart#L35

Therefore you need to do the following:

```
"cryptoAddresses": FieldValue.arrayUnion(['data1','data2','data3'])
```

In your case, it's probably going to be:

```
"cryptoAddresses": FieldValue.arrayUnion([coinAddress])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the second problem by creating a third function:

```dart
  Future storeValues(coinAddress) async {
    final walletToUser = await addWalletToUser(coinAddress);
    final wallet = await createWallet(coinAddress);
    return [walletToUser,wallet];
  }
```

and by calling that function with `.then()` like so:

```dart
 storeValues(_textController.text).then((val) {
                      if (val[0] != null && val[1] != null) {
                      //do something here
}}
```